# Is there a way to do a conditional regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression

[screenshot from the paper "Momentum Crashes" by Daniel and Moskowitz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Es6.png)

so a stands for alpha, ß for beta. 
I is a dummy variable

The model im trying to replicate is written like this, and in the solution table there are values for alpha zero and alpha (i). So is it possible to do a regression with two alphas and two betas if my dummy variable is one ? or is it just two separate regressions using subset?
The Authors call it a conditional CAPM.

```
reg<-      lm(Momentum.monthly$WMLRF[25:1044]~Fama.French.monthly$Mkt[25:1044],sub      set = Fama.French.monthly$bear.indicator == 0)
```

This was my try, but the values don't fit with the solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your model ? Especially the effect of Rm

Comment: added a screenshot from what im trying to replicate. 
my Model just regresses the Momentum return on the Market return, given the Indikator is zero.